# How to call servlets using AJS in JIRA plugin?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I know a way to call REST APIs using AJS.

I want to call POST of servlet using AJS. Via given docs, I could only  find a way to call GET of servlets via hitting **http://localhost:2990/jira/plugins/servlet/{servletURL}**  in browser. Is there a way to call same url with POST method using **AJS**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AJAX` calls

```
AJS.$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:2990/jira/plugins/servlet/{servletURL}",
  type: "GET",
  data: ({projectsOnly : "true"}),
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg){
    alert(msg);
  }
});
```

see their [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/gadgets/making-ajax-calls/)